# Using nested controllers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a child controller used two times in a page.

When a function is called from the HTML within the child controller, that function (in this child controller) is called correctly, but there is a scope variable update in that function. When the scope variable is updated, the corresponding html code is not updated. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="projectResourceManagementCtrl" class="view-content my-switch-animation">
  <div id="project-list-sortby-container" ng-controller="childController"> 
    <select ng-change="functionInChildCtr()">
  </div>
</div>

<div ng-include="'tpl.html'" ng-controller="childController"></div>
```

Comment: Most probably scoping issue. Please share your html, and do yourself a favor and read https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Just put that scope variable into an object in scope not directly in scope, this way the value will be added in inheritance chain, and will be available for the parent.

Comment: need to know more 1)is your scope variable a primitive or an object.2)in which controllers scope is your  html code that needs to be updated.go through this to get a larger picture http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Comment: The html is in child controller scope

Comment: My variable is a primitive. Now I made that as an object. As you said the variable is updating correctly, but still html is not updated.